# Need to download the PDF, NOT the content of the webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, python-requests

So as it stands I am able to get the content of the webpage of the PDF link [EXAMPLE OF THE LINK HERE](http://msds.walmartstores.com/client/document?productid=1000527&productguid=54e8aa24-0db4-4973-a81f-87368312069a&DocumentKey=undefined&HazdocumentKey=undefined&MSDS=0&subformat=NAM) BUT, I don't want the content of the webpage I want the content of the PDF so I can put the content into a PDF on my computer in a folder.

I have been successful in doing this on sites that I don't need to log into and without a proxy server.

Relevant CODE:

```
import os
import urllib2
import time
import requests
import urllib3
from random import *


s = requests.Session()
data = {"Username":"username", "Password":"password"}
url = "https://login.url.com"

print "doing things"
r2 = s.post(url, data=data, proxies = {'https' : 'https://PROXYip:PORT'}, verify=False)

#I get a response 200 from printing r2
print r2


downlaod_url = "http://msds.walmartstores.com/client/document?productid=1000527&productguid=54e8aa24-0db4-4973-a81f-87368312069a&DocumentKey=undefined&HazdocumentKey=undefined&MSDS=0&subformat=NAM"

file = open("F:\my_filepath\document" + str(maxCounter) + ".pdf", 'wb')
temp = s.get(download_url, proxies = {'https' : 'https://PROXYip:PORT'}, verify=False)

#This prints out the response from the proxy server (i.e. 200)
print temp

something = uniform(5,6)
print something
time.sleep(something)

#This gets me the content of the web page, not the content of the PDF
print temp.content

file.write(temp.content)
file.close()
```

**I need help figuring out how to "download" the content of the PDF**

Comment: Your trying to download the PDF in the URL you provided or did I misunderstood you ? cause I'm having no trouble doing that

Comment: @EvyatarMeged Yep, that's what I want to do, I want to download the PDF. Oh, oops I forgot to include download_url declaration

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://msds.walmartstores.com/client/document?productid=1000527&productguid=54e8aa24-0db4-4973-a81f-87368312069a&DocumentKey=undefined&HazdocumentKey=undefined&MSDS=0&subformat=NAM'

pdf = requests.get(url)
with open('walmart.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(pdf.content)
```

**Edit**

Try again with a requests session to manage cookies (assuming they send you those after login) and also maybe a different proxy

```
proxy_dict = {'https': 'ip:port'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    # Authentication request, use GET/POST whatever is needed
    # data variable should hold user/password information
    auth = session.get(login_url, data=data, proxies=proxy_dict, verify=False)
    if auth.status_code == 200:
        print(auth.cookies) # Tell me if you got anything
        pdf = auth.get('download_url')  # Were continuing the same session
        with open('walmart.pdf', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(pdf.content)
    else:
        print('No go, got {0} response'.format(auth.status_code))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me, I'm going to edit your answer to show you your modified code to fit my program

Comment: With out the inclusion of data=data to the requests I get a response 200, but when I go to open the PDF in a folder I get the error: "Could not open "walmart.pdf" because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged"

Comment: You don't need to send any data for fetching the PDF file in the get request. If I understand correctly, your authenticating to some website via POST ? I'll edit my answer in a minute to try and fit yours.

Comment: It doesn't work, I get a response 411, and I've been doing some reading and I might switch to urllib3